# How to go to previous activity if the activity is killed by Android runtime?

Tags: android

I had a problem with an app, i.e., when I am moving to the previous window the control goes to the splash screen of my app because the previous activity is killed by the Android runtime.

How do I keep the previous activity alive, or how can I create the activity again and access it from the present activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of a default constructor to close and open the screen.

If you want to move between screens:

```
1-2-3-4

  &&

4-3-2-1
```

Android itself will take care of it.

For example, if you want traverse in a specific way like 
    4-2-3-1
Android doesn't allow you, so simply create a constructor and assign present activity to it and make use of that variable to close the screen at any time.

For example, here is the activity class

```
public class One extends Activity 
{

    private One Screen;

    public One()
    {
        Screen=this;
    }

}
```

When you want close this activity simply use:

```
Screen.finish();
```

instead of

```
this.finish();
```

When you want invoke new activity of your liking, simply use

```
Screen.finish();
Intent i = new Intent(One.this, YourActivity.class);
Log.i(TAG, "calling YourActivity Screen");
startActivity(i);
```

If you want pass any data between the screens, you can make use of

```
i.putExtra("valuename", actualvalue);
```

and you can  retrive the value using

```
Intent startIntent = getIntent();
String actualvalue = startIntent.getStringExtra("valuename");
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have a Splash activity, I think the correct way is closing in and starting the main activity

```
Intent mainIntent =new Intent(Splash.this,MainActivity.class);
Splash.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
Splash.this.finish();
```

Then, from your main activity start calling your subactivities.

Why has it killed your main activity? Are you calling `finish()`?

Comment: i am not calling finish() in app due to less space it is killed by runtime, my problem is when you want traverse b/w multiple screen (activities) u need go back to home screen in the same u entered in to the present screen but the previous activities are killed then how do we make this thing happen to see that we can traverse all the    
screens in opp direction, plz help me